# Project Manager in Ice Breaker Team. What does Ice Breaker Team mean?

Tags: new-job, hiring

I have noticed a job announcement with title **Project Manager in Ice Breaker Team** in a software company.

What does Ice Breaker Team mean?

Comment: We might need a bit more context. Is there no job description where you saw the announcement? Could be someone who helps ease tensions in teams, or it's project manager of an arctic expedition...

Comment: @Kozaky It is a role in a SW company, not an arctic expedition

Comment: Could also mean a team which works in emerging markets

Comment: Is this an internal (within your own company) or external (public internet) job listing?

Comment: Something to do with snowcones I think

Comment: it just means they are (supposedly) the "advance technology" team, the "R&D" team that does the "cutting edge" stuff.   I wouldn't work with a company that uses such hokey terms  :)

Comment: @Fattie you are right about the team does the "cutting edge" stuff. If you like you can post as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 5):

You should ask the employer. Only they can know the answer. The description of the job is more important, as well as the benefits.

It can mean anything:

- early prototyping;
- tension-breaking;
- first team formed in the company;
- just a (pseudo- / almost) random name for a team - with no other implied meaning at all; it could be "The Three Little Bears" as well;
- and many others...

Comment: Your fourth comment here would more commonly be termed as a "project code name" - usually this would be an internal-facing opportunity where employees are expected to know what these weird names mean.

Comment: @Snow: you are right. I just made a reference to the title of the question, which uses the word "Team". Also, one may come with the idea to have one name for the project and another name for the team. And so on :) +1

Comment: A "funny" story - my own experience long in the past. Direct manager gathers the team to make some organizational announcements. One of them was something like: ""Person X was promoted to the position of [SomeRandomLetters]". Out of pure curiosity, I asked what the [SomeRandomLetters] means. Although the direct manager got angry at me that I did not such an "obvious" thing - it was also obvious that the manager did not know either. Conclusion: even the company may not know why they called something in a certain way.

Answer (score 2):

**Best guess: This is simply the name of the team within the company**. The company might use it to identify that team and might have thought it sounds cool enough to use in their job ad.

The name might or might not also tell a bit about what they do. Looking at the job ad (yes it's apparently easy enough to google it), this is a customer facing team  where "You will be part of demonstrator projects with latest technology" - so the name might refer to breaking the ice with new customers.